# Links on website load in iFrame scrolled to top

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-browser

[My portfolio site](http://www.ellenportercreative.com) has links to different pages that load in an IFrame to the right. I want the pages to always load at the top -- therefore added this code in the head tag of the child pages:

```
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript'> 
    parent.document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  </script>
</head>
```

It works in Safari but not Firefox or Chrome.... What will work in all browsers?

Thanks!